# Hazelcast Cache Manager: Cannot overwrite a Cache's CacheManager

Tags: spring, testng, hazelcast

On an application I am working I am trying to upgrade from Hazelcast 3.6 to 3.12.4 and I am encountering some problems which reproduce easily when two or more tests are ran together. The tests are all annotated with `@WebAppConfiguration` and include the Spring's application configuration using `ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class})`

As part of the configuration, I have a `@Bean` that called `CacheAwareStorage` that initiates the `CacheManager`. THe initialization is quite basic:

```
public Cache<T, V> initCache(String name, Class<T> type, Class<T> valueType) {
    Cache<T, V> cache = manager.getCache(cacheName, keyType, valueType);
    if (cache != null)
    {
        return cache;
    }
    cache = manager.createCache(cacheName, config);
    return cache;
 }
```

The problem occurs when the context is refreshed as part of the test suit, which I think is done in `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` since I don't explicitly refresh the context. The following error occurs which result sin only the first class of tests to pass:

```
GenericWebApplicationContext: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@6170989a
....
WARN GenericWebApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
....
Factory method 'tokenStore' threw exception
     nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot overwrite a Cache's CacheManager.
```

Looking over what has changed, I see that the `AbstracthazelcastCacheManager` throws an `IllegalStateException` which comes from the Hazelcast `CacheProxy`. To be more precise, the `manager.getCache()` -> `getCacheUnchecked()` -> creates a cache proxy in `createCacheProxy()` -> and set's the proxy's manager to the current manager in `cacheProxy.setCacheManager()`. 
Starting with Hazelcast v3.9, this is no longer allowed once the manager has already been set.

What would be a solution for this? It may be that there is a bug in Hazelcast (there is no check if the manager that is being set is actually different than the already existing one), however I am looking for something that I can do on my side. Why the 'getCache()' tries to re-create the proxy is another thing that I do not understand.

I assume that I must do something so that the Context is not refreshed, however I don't know how (if at all) I can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was due to the way the Cache manager Bean was created. I used the internal Hazelcast cache manager and a new instance was created each time. Using the JCache API as bellow, solved the problem

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    HazelcastServerCachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider(); // or add class name of Hazelcast server caching provider to disambiguate
    return provider.getCacheManager(null, null, HazelcastCachingProvider.propertiesByInstanceItself(HAZELCAST_INSTANCE));
}
```

Help received from Hazelcast team on this: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/16212